# how to Implementing Custom Data Serialization and Deserialization in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, object-relationships

I'm working on a project that requires me to implement custom data serialization and deserialization in C# without relying on third-party libraries. This task involves handling complex data structures and preserving object relationships.

I have a class hierarchy that includes multiple custom classes, and I need to convert objects of these classes into a custom binary format for efficient storage and transmission.

Here's a simplified sample example of the class hierarchy:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking for guidance on how to implement custom serialization and deserialization for these classes. What are the best practices, design patterns, and C# features I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at official documentation, [Serialization in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/).

There is [System.Runtime.Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization?view=net-7.0) namespace which contains [ISerializable Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?view=net-7.0) that allows you to control serialization and deserialization of an object.

In your case you might want to follow [Custom binary serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/fundamentals/serialization/binary/custom-serialization) to achieve desired output.